# Good way to clone an object

Tags: c#, .net, clone

I have to clone some Entity, then I wrote this piece of code.

```
public override object Clone()
{
  var CloneUser = base.Clone() as FMSUser;

  CloneUser.Username = this.Username;
  CloneUser.IsEnabled = this.IsEnabled;
  CloneUser.IsNeedPasswordReset = this.IsNeedPasswordReset;
  CloneUser.LastName = this.LastName;
  CloneUser.FirstName = this.FirstName;
  CloneUser.MiddleName = this.MiddleName;
  CloneUser.DistributorID = this.DistributorID;
  CloneUser.IsLocked = this.IsLocked;

  return CloneUser;
}
```

But then my coworker sent me this code, saying it's better to clone this way, but can't tell me why :

```
public FMSUser(FMSUser user)
{   
  this.Username = user.Username;
  this.IsEnabled = user.IsEnabled;
  this.IsNeedPasswordReset = user.IsNeedPasswordReset;
  this.LastName = user.LastName;
  this.FirstName = user.FirstName;
  this.MiddleName = user.MiddleName;
  this.DistributorID = user.DistributorID;
  this.IsLocked = user.IsLocked;
}
public override object Clone()
{
  return new FMSUser(this);
}
```

**Can anynone explain me why the second way is better?**

Comment: You should avoid `Clone` in general. Instead provide a `DeepClone` method(or whatever name you want). You don't know how `Clone` is implemented, using deep or shallow copy.

Comment: It's not better, it's just wrapped so the code can be used from parameter-based contructor. But keep in mind the second method doesn't do anything with the base class, so it looks like the base is gonna have default values instead of cloned ones.

Comment: I don't think Clone is the best way to do this. You could use reflection instead and clone the properties dynamically, that way you won't have to worry about changes in the classes as long as the properties are identical(same type, name, etc) and accessible from one object to another.

Comment: This sounds like a question for CodeReview?

Comment: From your code it seems like CloneUser is not a class that needs to be in your main class. Your co-worker seems like wanted to remove the confusion between CloneUser and FMSUser.

Comment: If he can't tell you why it is better, it is not better, it is just an opinion. The first method does something with the base class, the second just ignores the base class properties. Without the whole implementation, we can't tell if it makes a difference.

Comment: Here's a great SO discussion covering this exact topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Answer (score 1):

Clone() is ambiguous and even Microsoft recommends not implementing ICloneable

What I think is cleaner is just a ctor that takes the object
Clone in that ctor

```
 FMSUser copyUser = new FMSUser(existingUser);
```

Then also have a method

```
 public FMSUser DeepClone() 
 {
    return new FMSUser(this);
 }
```

[ICloneable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Object.MemberwiseClone Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Down vote care to comment?

Comment: I saw your message right now. Sorry I thought I gave you up vote. Apologizes.

Answer (score -2):

If your object is serializable.

```
public static T Clone<T>(T obj)
{
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
   ms.Position = 0;

   return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
 }
}
```

Comment: You should add the object must be marked as serializable and other caveates